# React state not updating to show the next URI image in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a react state at my disposal. I have a server which takes an image and no matter what, for the same user, it save the image as:
http://192.168.43.102/public/images/profile/5896475365.jpg

Now I have a component where I have this state. The image changes in the server. Images changes everyone on the same url as above but react native useState() doesn't seem to care for some reason.

My component:

```
function Profile(props) {


    let {name, number: phoneNumber, rating, uri: profileImage, user: token, setUser} = useAuth();
    let setName, setProfileImage;
    [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState(profileImage);
    [name, setName] = useState(name);
    const [changes, onChanges] = useState(false);
    let [previousName, setPreviousName] = useState(name);
    let [previousImage, setPreviousImage] = useState(profileImage);


    const updateData = async (token, setUser) => {
        console.log(`Token inside updateData: ${token}`);
        if(!token) return;
        console.log(`Name: ${name}`);
        console.log(`Previous Name: ${previousName}`);
        console.log(`Previous Uri: ${previousImage}`);
        console.log(`Current Uri: ${profileImage}`);
        if(previousName !== name){ 
            const { data: newToken } = await personalApi.updateProfileName(name);
            await personalApi.updateUser(newToken, setUser);
            setPreviousName(name);
        }
        if(previousImage !== profileImage){
            const { data: newToken } = await personalApi.updateProfilePicture(profileImage, token);
            await personalApi.updateUser(newToken, setUser);
            setPreviousImage(profileImage);
        }
    }

    const nameChange = text => {
        if(text !== previousName) onChanges(true);
        else onChanges(false);
        setName(text);
    }

    const selectImage = async () => {
        try{
            const {cancelled, uri} = await ImageSelector.launchImageLibraryAsync();
            if(!cancelled){ onChanges(true); setProfileImage(uri); }

        } catch(error) {
            console.log("An error selecting the image.", error);
        }
    }    

    const requestImagePermission = async () => {
        const { granted } = await ImageSelector.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if(!granted) alert('You need to enable image permission');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        requestImagePermission();
    }, [])

    return (
        <Screen styles={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={selectImage} style={styles.profileImageContainer}>
                    <Image style={styles.profileImage} source = {{ uri: profileImage}} />
                </TouchableOpacity> 
                <TextInput
                    label="Name"
                    value={name}
                    onChangeText={text => nameChange(text)}
                    style={[styles.textInputs, {marginTop: 80}]}
                />
                <TextInput
                    label="Rating"
                    value={rating}
                    style={styles.textInputs}
                    editable={false}
                />
                <TextInput
                    label="Phone Number"
                    value={phoneNumber}
                    style={styles.textInputs}
                    editable={false}
                />
                 <AppButton 
                 text="Save changes"
                 style={changes ? [styles.button, styles.buttonActive] : [styles.button, styles.buttonInactive]}
                 onPress={() => {updateData(token, setUser)}} />
            </ScrollView>
        </Screen>
    );
}
```

Now here I am giving profile image to my image component. The image at that url changes on update but react is not willing to.

Please reason it out.

PS: The image changes when I select an image because then the uri of the format within the phone but  when I refresh my app it seems that it just saved the image it found before at that url and showed that image only which is not what I want.